# Разделение входящего трафика с помощью iptables

Tags: iptables, ubuntu, сервер

Входящий 2 гб трафик  Надо нарезать каналы на две сети по 1 ГБ на каждую сеть, используя iptables. Подскажите как.

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал следующий вариант:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d DST_NETWORK -m limit --limit 22/sec --limit-burst 300 -j ACCEPTiptables -A FORWARD -d DST_NETWORK -j DROP
```

> **limit** - Устанавливается средняяскорость "освобождения емкости" заединицу времени. В качестве аргументауказывается число пакетов и время.Допустимыми считаются следующиеединицы измерения времени: /second/minute /hour /day.
>
> **limit-burst** - Устанавливаетмаксимальное значение числа burstlimit для критерия limit. Это числоувеличивается на единицу если полученпакет, подпадающий под действиеданного правила, и при этом средняяскорость (задаваемая ключом --limit)поступления пакетов уже достигнута.Так происходит до тех пор, пока числоburst limit не достигнет максимальногозначения, устанавливаемого ключом--limit-burst. После этого правило начинает пропускать пакеты соскоростью, задаваемой ключом --limit.

Но не следует забывать, что это скорость в пакетах в секунду. Т.е. если отбросить мелкие пакеты (что не очень хорошо) можно для вашего случая рассчитать скорость канала: 1Гб * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 1500 (размер фрейма в байтах) = 715 827 пакетов, что не совсем приемлемо для iptables.

Для нарезки трафика я бы советовал использовать утилиту `tc`. А с ней cbq и htb. Последние настраиваются достаточно просто, причем значения будут в байтах. А iptables оставить для других целей.